# What elevation are each of my slopes at?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, slope

I am working on a DEM in a sand dune ecosystem, I also have a raster of slope data ranging from 0 to around 20 degree slopes which has been reclassified to 6 categories (1-6) and polygons of the slope categories created in order to find out how much vegetation is present at each slope angle polygon.

However I have decided to separate the slopes that occur at low elevations and those that occur at high elevations so as to distinguish whether there are slopes with a small angle at the top of dunes that may have a different environment for vegetation.

I have detrended my DEM so that it is easier to tell what is sand dune and what is interdune areas and to account for the natural slope of the land but I dont know how to find out which slopes are at higher/lower areas of the DEM, does anyone know how I might do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [combine](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combine.htm) tool. For this, first reclassify your DEM into two categories and create a new column, say Dune_Class which will have your specifications for each category (dune and inter-dune). Combine will summarise each cell with attributes from combined rasters, which you can process it further.